# What is a QPRJX Word™?

Tags: word-property

<sub>*This puzzle is based on and inspired by the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) series started by JLee that have grown into Word™, [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=what%20is%20a%20phrase%E2%84%A2), and [Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it QPRJX Word™.

This is a list of QPRJX Word™ and Not QPRJX Word™.

| QPRJX Word™ | Not QPRJX Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| the | weird |
| first | last |
| dumb | clever |
| looked | correspond |
| straw | performance |
| misery | patent |
| chain | graze |
| lobby | compensation |
| random | acquaintance |
| cash | hammer |

Here is the CSV version:

```
QPRJX Word™,Not QPRJX Word™
the,weird
first,last
dumb,clever
looked,correspond
straw,performance
misery,patent
chain,graze
lobby,compensation
random,acquaintance
cash,hammer
```

What is the rule to determine if the word is QPRJX Word™ or not?

**Bonus: Why is it called QPRJX Word™?**

*Hint 1:*

> [image]

*Hint 2:*

> QAZWSXEDCRFVTGB

Comment: Just a note: you don't need to worry at all if someone doesn't solve the question *immediately*. *In general*, new hints are given after a day or so passes, to allow people in all timezones to have a crack at it. But don't feel obligated to ever give or remove a hint, do what you want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe a word passes the rule if

> When typing the word on a QWERTY keyboard, the paths taken to each letter should not intersect. This is more easily demonstrated with imaginary lines as shown below

> 1st QPRJX Word™ - misery
>  [image: misery]

> 2nd QPRJX Word™ - random
>  [image: random]

> We can see that there are no intersecting lines. This also applies to all the other given words. Let's look at some words that do not satisfy this rule too

> 1st not QPRJX Word™ - graze
>  [image: graze]

> 2nd not QPRJX Word™ - patent
>  [image: patent]

> Again, intersecting lines will be found in all words that are listed under not QPRJX Word™

> That being said, I have no idea why it is called QPRJX Word™

Comment: The answer was marked as accepted, but we still don't know why it's called a QPRJX Word. In fact, "qprjx" doesn't appear to be a QPRJX Word, according to this answer, since "QP" and "PR" overlap. Also, this doesn't work super well with the "QAZWSXEDCRFVTGB" clue, which seems to imply we should care about the **columns** on the qwerty keyboard.